# Why can't CocoaPods access RealmSwift

Tags: cocoapods, realm

I'm trying to use Realm with Swift 2.0
My Podfile is pretty simple:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.2.0'

# Realm Frameworks
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

But I'm getting

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `RealmSwift (from `https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git`, branch `swift-2.0`)` required by `Podfile`
```

The Podfile looks well formed to me. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you used Realm Frameworks in other projects? I've had that issue before (with another Pod), turns out it was the Pod i was trying to use, not my Podfile.

Comment: I just tried your Podfile and it installs without problems. Is there anything else in the Podfile except from what you posted?

Comment: @ joem   No. That's it.  The only thing I posted incorrectly was that the line 'source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'' should have been in code format.

Comment: @joem I updated cocoapods to the latest version and got a more helpful message.  "Specs satisfying the `RealmSwift (from `https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git`, branch `swift-2.0`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."  I then upped the target to iOS9 and it installed.

Answer (score 1):

`swift-2.0` branch already has been merged into master a few weeks ago. Since Swift 2 was released officially. So you no longer need to specify `swift-2.0` branch if you use latest toolchains. You can just write `pod 'RealmSwift'`

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'RealmSwift'
```